# ADO Recordset fails to save into DOM XML

Tags: xml, dom, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

This recordset is failing to save into a DOM as XML.

Some of the column data has special characters in it. I can loop through each record and Response.Write() the fields without errors occuring.

```
Set adoCn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCn.Open Application("conn_string")
Set objCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objDOM = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")

objCommand.ActiveConnection = Application("conn_string")

spQry = "SP_QUERY"
objCommand.CommandText = spQry
objCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Set objRs = objCommand.Execute

objRS.save objDOM, adPersistXML //Error occurs here
Set objCommand = Nothing
objRS.Close
adoCn.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
```

> Error: Unknown Error

If I retype the text in the database, thus getting rid of the special characters, it all works fine.

I have tried adding the following to see if it helped but no luck so far:

```
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.Charset="UTF-8"
```

Does anyone know how I can save this recordset into the DOM whether it has special characters or not?

**[EDIT]** Added image of text
[image]

**[EDIT2]** Attempt to stream recordset after executing query:

Unfortunately I didn't get very far with this, when setting the Charset it gave an error: `"The parameter is incorrect"`, the error actually occurs on the `oStream.ReadText` line. When I comment out the Charset, the Response.Write at the end only shows the square brackets.

```
Set objRs = objCommand.Execute

sXML = ""

Set oStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oStream.Charset = "utf-8" //This produced an error: The parameter is incorrect 

oRecordset.save oStream, adPersistXML
oStream.Position = 0

sXML = oStream.ReadText 

oStream.Close 
Set oStream = Nothing

Response.Write("[" & sXML & "]")
```

Comment: Can you give examples of the special characters?

Comment: @oraclecertifiedprofessional absolutely see above edit, towards the end of the first paragraph in the word "elses". I think there are other characters however they don't display, because I tried deleting the one just mentioned but it was still giving an error.

Comment: hmm, looking at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681501(v=vs.85).aspx) it notes `A Recordset saved in XML format is saved using UTF-8 format. When such a file is loaded into an ADO Stream, the Stream object will not attempt to open a Recordset from the stream unless the Charset property of the stream is set to the appropriate value for UTF-8 format.` I wonder if your special characters cause the Stream to be created in an unsupported Charset. You could try using an `ADODB.Stream` instead, which allows you to explicitly state the target Charset.

Comment: Gave the streaming a shot however didn't get very far, maybe you could help me with an example. See Edit2 above.

Comment: Sorry, I think I must have a different version of ADODB installed because I can't reproduce the error. I've found [other](http://www.aspmessageboard.com/showthread.php?229139-The-Paramenter-is-Incorrect) [mentions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/87774a88-bf06-4083-bac2-72db528628c9/ado-stream-reader-issue) of this issue (seems to be related to copy 'n paste from Office documents with "smart" quotes) but no resolution

Comment: So you can Response.Write sXML (streamed xml string) just fine?

Comment: yes, I'm afraid so. All I can suggest is attempt to upgrade/reinstall ADODB and try again or run a one-time process of normalising your data to swap your special characters with appropriate replacements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find no way to display the data. So I manually altered the text in the db, as there were only 4 records.

I ended up fighting this problem at the data entry side, when the form data is processed and inserted or updated.

I looped through the text analyzing each character stripping all non keyboard characters producing a clean string.